# Местоположение пользователя и стандартная метка "Мое местоположение"

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Можно ли определив местоположение пользователя вывести его на карту отметив стандартной меткой Яндекса (Я - в красном круге)? В текущей реализации я определяю местоположение и добавляю метку на карту, но при нажатии на кнопку "Моё местоположение" добавляется метка к уже созданной мной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я знаю в API первой версии для этой метки был свой стиль который можно было использовать.

Соответственно два вопроса:

- можно ли во второй версии API сгенерить метку (Я) вручную?
- есть ли возможность вызвать функцию которая тригерится при нажатии на кнопку "Мое местоположение"?

Answer (score 1):

ответ на оба вопроса - "да". В документации есть примеры https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.GeolocationControl-docpage/